# PHPDOC: option to hide undocumented members

Tags: php, phpdoc

I found that another tool (doxygen) has such an option (HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS). I wonder if there is something similar for phpDoc, except marking them all with the @ignore tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking them with @ignore is the only option.